# How do I slice a string in python based on the text, not the letter number?

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to automate some document editing and wondering if there's a way to program this to simplify it? I need to remove large portions of text that are in the center of a user input that varies each time but is surrounded by constants. For example, the user input would be a copy/paste in this format:

"A: Test Name Here

B: Test Date Here

C: Long details that are unnecessary here.

D: Summary here"

I would like to cut out C all the way up to the start of D to get:

"A: Test Name Here

B: Test Date Here

D: Summary here"

I want to do something like delete ["C" : "D" -1] and save the rest of the text. In the actual documents "C" is a more specific unique word and wouldn't actually delete every letter c in the text.

Seems simple but I can't figure it out. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Sounds like a use for Regular Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```py
import re

s = """\
A: Test Name Here
B: Test Date Here
C: Long details that are unnecessary here.
D: Summary here"""

print(s)
print("---------")
print(re.sub("C:[\s\S]*?(?=D:)", "", s))
```

Output:

```
A: Test Name Here
B: Test Date Here
C: Long details that are unnecessary here.
D: Summary here
---------
A: Test Name Here
B: Test Date Here
D: Summary here
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the output format that you specified, this will do the trick:

```python
import re

text = """A: Test Name Here 
B: Test Date Here
C: A looot of unnecessary staff here, including $ymbols and num3rs.
D: Summary here"""

reText = re.sub("C:.*\n* *?(?=D:)", "", text)

print(reText)
```

Or by opening a file:

```python
import re

fp = open("./text.txt", "r").read()

reText = re.sub("C:.*\n* *?(?=D:)", "", fp)

print(reText)
```

Output shown:

```
A: Test Name Here 
B: Test Date Here
D: Summary here
```